# Code to pick buckets for a list of value

Tags: python, collections

In my current project, I came across a scenario where there will be two sorted `list` of `Decimal` values. Let's call them `bucket_list` and `value_list`

1. Where `bucket_list` represents the sum of one or more elements from the `value_list`
2. `value_list` may have duplicate values
3. Every element in `value_list` should be picked only once (duplicate values are considered different elements)
4. In the end, all elements in `bucket_list` will have one or more element from `value_list` and no elements in `value_list` will be left without a mapping to `bucket_list`

After a lot of searches, I wrote the code with `backtracking` and `greedy`(I think). Below is the part of code that handles the part of the problem.

```py
    class FindBucketMap(object):
        @classmethod
        def create_map_list(cls, bucket_list: list, value_list: list, bucket_map_list: list, i: int = 0):
            """
        Backtracking code to find possible bucket and value pair
        :param bucket_list: List of bucket values
        :param value_list: List of values to map to bucket
        :param bucket_map_list: List will be updated with the mapping of values from bucket_list to value_list
        :param i:
        :return:
        """
            if i >= len(bucket_list) or len(value_list) == 0:
                if i >= len(bucket_list) and len(value_list) == 0:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            bucket_map_prospect_list = []
            bucket_value = bucket_list[i]
            cls.create_map(bucket_value, value_list, [], bucket_map_prospect_list)
            if len(bucket_map_prospect_list) == 0:
                return False
            for bucket_map_prospect in bucket_map_prospect_list:
                temp_list = list(value_list)
                for x in bucket_map_prospect:
                    temp_list.remove(x)
                if cls.create_map_list(bucket_list, temp_list, bucket_map_list, i + 1):
                    bucket_map_list.append({"bucket": bucket_value, "split": bucket_map_prospect})
                    return True

        @classmethod
        def create_map(cls, value: Decimal, value_list: list, cur_list: list, map_list: list, i: int = 0):
            """
        Greedy code to find list of values that matches a sum
        :param value:  Expected Sum
        :param value_list: Possible values
        :param cur_list: Processed values
        :param map_list: List contains the possible combinations
        :param i:
        :return:
        """
            if value == Decimal(0):
                map_list.append(cur_list)
                return
            if value < Decimal(0):
                return
            while i < len(value_list):
                if value < value_list[i]:
                    return
                cls.create_map(value - value_list[i], value_list, cur_list + [value_list[i]], map_list, i + 1)
                i += 1
```

Please give reviews on the approach and the code.

**EDIT 1:**

For a large test case ( `len(bucket_list) > 50` and `len(value_list) > 1000` ), the program almost never ends. So I changed the code to the following:

```py
    class FindBucketMap(object):
        @classmethod
        def create_map_list(cls, bucket_list: list, value_list: list, i: int = 0):
            if i >= len(bucket_list):
                return True
            return cls.create_map(bucket_list[i], bucket_list, value_list, [], i)

        @classmethod
        def create_map(cls, value: int, bucket_list: list, value_list: list, cur_list: list, i: int, j: int = 0):
            if value == 0:
                temp_list = list(value_list)
                for x in cur_list:
                   temp_list.remove(x)
                print(i, bucket_list[i], cur_list)
                result = cls.create_map_list(bucket_list, temp_list, i + 1)
                if result is True:
                    return [{"value": bucket_list[i], "split": cur_list}]
                elif isinstance(result, list):
                    return result + [{"value": bucket_list[i], "split": cur_list}]
                else:
                    return False
            if len(value_list) == 0 or value < Decimal(0):
                return False
            while j < len(value_list):
                if value < value_list[j]:
                    return False
                result = cls.create_map(value - value_list[j], bucket_list, value_list, cur_list + [value_list[j]], i,
                                        j + 1)
                if isinstance(result, list):
                    return result
                j += 1
            return False
```

This is faster than the first but still not fast enough.

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple ways to shorten your code

This code

```
if i >= len(bucket_list) or len(value_list) == 0:
    if i >= len(bucket_list) and len(value_list) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

can be written like this:

```
if i >= len(bucket_list) or not value_list:
    return i >= len(bucket_list) and not value_list
```

This allows you to return the boolean value this expression would evaluate too, and `not value_list` means the length of `value_list` is 0, or empty. I changed other occurances of this in your code as well.

---

This code

```
for x in bucket_map_prospect:
    temp_list.remove(x)
```

can be written like this:

```
temp_list.remove(x for x in bucket_map_prospect)
```

---

If you're going to use type hints, you might as well hint at what the method is returning. From this

```
def function(...):
```

to this

```
def function(...) -> bool/int/etc:
```

You'll see what I mean when you look at the updated code.

---

**Updated Code**

```
class FindBucketMap(object):
    """
    Class Docstring
    """
    @classmethod
    def create_map_list(cls, bucket_list: list, value_list: list, bucket_map_list: list, i: int = 0) -> bool:
        """
    Backtracking code to find possible bucket and value pair
    :param bucket_list: List of bucket values
    :param value_list: List of values to map to bucket
    :param bucket_map_list: List will be updated with the mapping of values from bucket_list to value_list
    :param i:
    :return:
    """
        if i >= len(bucket_list) or not value_list:
            return i >= len(bucket_list) and not value_list

        bucket_map_prospect_list = []
        bucket_value = bucket_list[i]
        cls.create_map(bucket_value, value_list, [], bucket_map_prospect_list)

        if not bucket_map_prospect_list:
            return False

        for bucket_map_prospect in bucket_map_prospect_list:
            temp_list = list(value_list)
            temp_list.remove(x for x in bucket_map_prospect)
            if cls.create_map_list(bucket_list, temp_list, bucket_map_list, i + 1):
                bucket_map_list.append({"bucket": bucket_value, "split": bucket_map_prospect})
                return True

    @classmethod
    def create_map(cls, value: Decimal, value_list: list, cur_list: list, map_list: list, i: int = 0) -> None:
        """
    Greedy code to find list of values that matches a sum
    :param value:  Expected Sum
    :param value_list: Possible values
    :param cur_list: Processed values
    :param map_list: List contains the possible combinations
    :param i:
    :return:
    """
        if value == Decimal(0):
            map_list.append(cur_list)
            return
        if value < Decimal(0):
            return
        while i < len(value_list):
            if value < value_list[i]:
                return
            cls.create_map(value - value_list[i], value_list, cur_list + [value_list[i]], map_list, i + 1)
            i += 1
```